# Java Spring + Bootstrap issue

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a web-Project in Java, using Spring framework combined with some of the most popular Bootstrap components and its css.

Im making a classic Registration page, with a text input form (in the controller I can easily retrieve the value by the request parameter*), and a Bootstrap Dropdown menu that I can't really seem to process correctly.

At the first time the menu was correctly populated, but as I clicked on something the text remained on "Dropdown", with some script I managed to change the text at least, but I don't know how to retrieve the menu value when i Submit and invoke the controller method.

The code of in my HTML is the following:

```
//This Script is meant to show the selected value in the dropdown menu

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function(){

          $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

            $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
             $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
          });

        });
    </script>

    <form action = "inserisciSquadra" class="registerForm col-xs-4" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome Squadra</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeSquadra" />
        <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" name="teamDrop">
        Giocatore
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

     <c:forEach items="${utentiSenzaSquadra}" var="users">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"/><c:out value="${users.value}"/></a></li>
        </c:forEach>
      </ul>
    </div>   

        </div>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated :)

- I know registration pages should use POST method, but it's not a user registration page and it doesn't contain sensible data.